# PopupWindow .showAsDropDown() unable to shift left or right (But up and down both work)

Tags: android, popupwindow

I've inflated a PopupWindow using the method `.showAsDropDown()` however I'm not sure why It's not allowing me to shift it right or left. It works perfectly fine when shifting up and down.

```
public class TestWindow extends PopupWindow {

    private final Context context;

    public TestWindow (Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;

        setupView();
    }

    private void setupView() {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.popup_window_wallet_options, null);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        setOutsideTouchable(true);
        setFocusable(true);
        setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.bgr_menu_clear_wallet));
        setElevation(SpacingUtils.convertIntToDP(context, 4));

        setContentView(view);
    }
}
```

```
PopupWindow popupWindow = new TestWindow(context);
popupWindow.showAsDropDown(anchorButton, 50, -30);
```

[image]

Shifting the menu up by 30 works perfectly fine, but also I'm trying to shift it towards the left and it's not working. What am I doing incorrectly?

**Note:**

I've already tried it with `50` and `-50` so I'm at lost why it's not moving horizontally

My `R.layout.popup_window_wallet_options`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bgr_menu_clear_wallet">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_wallet_qr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:text="Wallet QR"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_clear_wallet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:text="Clear wallet"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do have omit any special properties in the `...`. Probably something is causing it

Comment: I added what I have in the ```...``` in edit above. Have you tried my popup window and is it working for you?

Comment: I couldn't manage to reproduce this issue; but hopefully `showAtLocation()` can be a workaround for you

Comment: ```.showAsDropdown()``` is working for you? (letting you shift it right and left?)

Comment: Yes working normally.. Do you use a normal button; or is it the options menu button?

Comment: The anchorButton is an ImageView. Can you post your code + xml for it?

Comment: Nothing special, I just updated the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Disclaimer: This is not a direct fix to `showAsDropDown()`, but it could be a workaround with `showAtLocation()`.

By using the window decorView as the anchorView, and accumulating the actual anchorView location to x & y shift values.

```
int[] anchorView = new int[2];
anchorButton.getLocationInWindow(anchorView); // anchor button location in the window
popupWindow.showAtLocation(getWindow().getDecorView(), Gravity.NO_GRAVITY,
        anchorView[0] + 50,
        anchorView[1] + anchorButton.getHeight() -30);
```

UPDATE:

> The anchorButton is an ImageView. Can you post your code + xml for it

Nothing special than yours.
This is the popup window layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test clear"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The activity just has a button as the anchorView:

And calling it:

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
PopupWindow popupWindow = new TestWindow(MainActivity.this);
popupWindow.showAsDropDown(button, 50, -30);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but -50dp didn't do anything to shift it. Using -75dp, -100dp the popup window finally shifted left. My popup_window_layout didn't have any negative margins (check edit for layouyt) so I'm not sure why it didn't shift left with -50.

Comment: Probably it didn't work on certain API levels, I saw something like that; you may test it on different APIs

Comment: Not sure. I tried it on my API27 emulator and real device 30, 31. Same issue.